# Recursively reverse linked list

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list, reverse, singly-linked-list

I am having hard time understanding how this recursive code works, I have made drawings and run the code through `gdb`.

```
void RecursiveReverse(struct node** headRef) 
{
  struct node* first;
  struct node* rest;

  if (*headRef == NULL) return; // empty list base case

  first = *headRef; // suppose first = {1, 2, 3}
  rest = first->next; // rest = {2, 3}

  if (rest == NULL) return; // empty rest base case

  RecursiveReverse(&rest); // Recursively reverse the smaller {2, 3} case
                           // after: rest = {3, 2}

  first->next->next = first; // put the first element on the end of the list
  first->next = NULL;

  *headRef = rest; // fix the head pointer
}
```

I understand that while the recursion call stack is being built up and once the list contains only {3}, **empty rest base case** `if (rest == NULL)` is `true` for the first time.

---

After this, the recursion call stack starts to break and hits `first->next->next = first;` for the first time, with {2, 3},

Before this line is executed, output in `gdb`:

```
(gdb)p *first
{data = 2, next = 0x1003001f0}

(gdb) p *rest
{data = 3, next = 0x0}
```

After this line is executed,

```
(gdb) p *rest
{data = 3, next = 0x1003000a0}
```

---

Continuing with code execution to hit `first->next->next = first;`, the second time:

```
(gdb) p **head_ref
{data = 1, next = 0x1003000a0}

(gdb) p *rest
{data = 3, next = 0x1003000a0} // expected p *rest to be 2
```

Here I expected that the local pointer `rest` should point to node 2, because while building up recursion call stack, `**headRef` pointed to node 1 and after line `rest = first->next;`, got executed `rest` pointed to node 2.

After `*headRef = rest;`, is executed, shouldn't `headRef` point to node 2?

How come that local state is lost and rest points to node 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that you have a list and its rest part is already reversed.

Before reversing the rest part the list had this structure

```
first -> first_of_rest -> second_of_rest->...->nth_of_rest->nullptr
```

After reversing the rest part you will get

```
first -> nullptr <- first_of_rest <- second_of_rest <-...<-nth_of_rest
         |                                                      |
         ________________________________________________________
                            the rest part of the list
```

So the data member next of the node `first` points to `first_of_rest` while the data member next of the node `first_of_rest` "points" to nullptr.

So what we need to do at this moment is to set the data member of the node `first_of_rest` to point to the node `first`

```
first->next->next = first;
```

abd set the data member next of the node `first` to "point" to nullptr.

```
first->next = NULL;
```

Thus we have

```
nullptr <-first <- first_of_rest <- second_of_rest <-...<-nth_of_rest
```

Comment: The hardest part is accepting the concept that the `RecursiveReverse(&rest)` does in fact reverse the rest.

Comment: @HasloVardos It is enough to consider one of the base cases when the list has only two elements.

Comment: After reversing the rest part, when the list looks like `1->2<-3` with `2->next` containing `null`, why doesn't line `*headRef = rest;` change `*headRef` to point to node 2, just like it did change `*headRef` to point to node 3, when the list contained only {2, 3}? How is `rest equal to {3,...}` always after that?

Comment: @HasloVardos The head is passed by reference. See the function parameter declaration  struct node** headRef. and the last statement of the function *headRef = rest;

Comment: So, only when in base case {2, 3}, the `*headRef = rest` actually modifies head to point to rest `rest equal to 3`, after that this assignment operation becomes irrelevant, as it does the same thing?

Comment: @HasloVardos The last statement is called in each invocation of the function except when the head is null. But the head is always set to rest.

Comment: And since, the head is passed by reference, `rest` is not the same as it was during the execution of function when the recursion stack was being built up? As if it would have been so, `rest` would be equal to 2->3, when list looks like `1->2<-3`  with `2->next` containing `null`, if I am not wrong?

Comment: @HasloVardos After the base case with two nodes rest will point to the second node of the list, that is after the call RecursiveReverse(&rest); and it will not be changed after exiting enclosed recursive calls.

Comment: Since, `struct node* rest;` is local variable to each function call to `RecursiveReverse(&rest);` and rest is set by line `rest = first->next;`. Eg {1,2,3} sets rest to {2, 3} in recursion call stack building phase, I assumed it will be remembered in the phase when function continues with lines after `RecursiveReverse(&rest);`  in recursion call stack breaking phase.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simplified pseudo code. It basically work like this:

```
RecursiveReverse(head):
    if head is empty:
        return
    RecursiveReverse(head->next)

    // When we come here, the whole list except the first
    // element has been reversed. So all that's left to do
    // is to reverse the final step

    head->next->next = head
    head->next = NULL
```

The most important thing to realize here is that AFTER the recursive call, the whole list EXCEPT the first element has been reversed.